# How to detect that large pandas dataframe has different data then before

Tags: python, pandas, large-data

I process large >1GB csv files with pandas. The script should detect if the data in dataframe is different to the data in the previos run. I can't store the past dataframe.
I'm looking for fast function which returns a kind of hash value from pandas dataframe. So that I could store and compare only those "hash-like" values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import joblib
joblib.hash(df)
```

This should work?

Also this undocumented hash exists in [pandas 20.1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.2/pandas/core/util/hashing.py#L57-L136):

```
from pandas.util import hash_pandas_object
h = hash_pandas_object(df)
```

just call `.sum()` if you want an overall value rather than per series as `hash_pandas_object` returns.

Comment: joblib.hash(df) won't work for me because hash(df.copy()) != hash(df). 
hash_pandas_object(df.copy()) == hash_pandas_object(df)  - this is better!